# Mails deleted in android gmail app are not deleted from server

Tags: gmail, delete

I have installed android on my HT device.. when I delete the mails from android gmail app, they are still available on server and i can see them using gmail web page..

can anyone give me solution?

happened again after flashing the ROM again and restored with titanium backup :(

Comment: How often are you syncing?

Comment: Someone's adding downvotes for a number of questions. This one's perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the gmail app or the HTC mail app?

The first one, gmail app, will have everything synced right away.

The other option, using HTC mail will be using a pop/imap account for accessing your Gmail. In that case you can update the pop/imap settings in your gmail account logging in with a browser and going to your settings. There you can choose if you want messages to be deleted or not.

Comment: I was using Gmail app.. I have reinstall the android again and now its ok. I think the problem was because of titanium backup. I think problem started after i restore the system using titanium backup. May be it messed with some settings..

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem today on my S3, although it wasn't just deleting that didn't work. Nothing I did within my phone's GMail app would sync properly--archiving, marking as read, etc.

I was able to fix it by clearing cache, and clearing data (both found on the App info page--Settings->Manage Apps). Once I did this, I had to reboot, as GMail kept crashing. After a reboot, everything was back to normal.